# Wordpress: get_attached_media('image') sorted by title

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

I want to get all the images attached to a specific post. This works just fine with:

```
$media = get_attached_media('image');
```

What I need now, is to sort these images by their title. I can already produce a list of the titles that are in the array:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($media); $i++) {
  get_the_title(array_keys($media)[$i])
}
```

I have no idea how to sort this by title. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be better to fetch the attachments already ordered instead of ordering the result array, right? This would save you code, headaches and processing.

If you look at WP Codex, [`get_attached_media()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media) calls [`get_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children), which calls [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) (yeah, that escalated quickly). In WordPress, attachments (and pretty much almost anything) is a `post` in essence.

Having all that in mind, this should fetch you the **list of images attached to a post ordered by title**:

```
$media = get_posts(array(
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

---

**Edit:** As pointed out by [ViszinisA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656976/viszinisa) and [Pieter Goosen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1908141/pieter-goosen), I changed the call to `get_posts()` directly. There was no point into calling `get_children()`.

**Note:** The `'post_parent'` parameter is needed, so I added it using `get_the_ID()` as it's value. Keep in mind that you **need to be within the loop** for `get_the_ID()` to retrieve the **current post ID**. When using outside the loop, you should change this parameter value accordingly to the context.

Comment: Why not just call get_posts() directly then?

Comment: `ordeby` should be `title`, not `post_title`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was easy and I like it to call the basic funtion right away. It gives much more control!

Comment: One small thing that was overlooked... Sebastian first said "I want to get all the images attached to a specific post." So you would want to add this to the array above too. posts_per_page' => -1